# Two Subjects in Sentence

Tags: grammar

> Energy production from coal in Germany followed a similar pattern, beginning the period at
>   just under 60% and falling significantly, though unlike Denmark it fell to a low of only 5% in 2007 and then increased again to approximately 18%.

The previous sentence contains two subjects, namely "Energy Production" and "it".  Normally I thought that a sentence could only have a single subject, however this appears to have two even though it is also referring to energy production.  Is there a particular grammar rule which relates to this?

> The students from the school are good, they study very hard.

This is a simplified example, but i'm unsure as to whether it is correct or not?

Comment: Each clause may have its own subject. *Energy production* is the subject of the independent clause; *it" is the subject of the dependent clause starting with *though*. Your "simplified" example is a run-on sentence, a mispunctuated joining of two independent clauses.

Comment: You yourself use _three_ in 'Normally, **I** thought, **a sentence** could only have a single subject; however, **this** appears to have two ...'. However, '... though unlike Denmark it ...' isn't too hot.

Comment: The students from the school are good AND they study very hard. OR The students from the school are good; they study very hard. Your sentence is a screwed up COMPOUND sentence.

Comment: I think it should more properly say *"though, unlike **in** Denmark, it fell to a low..."* since "it" is presumably referring to "Energy production from coal" rather than "Energy production from coal in Germany".

Comment: It's because the _it_ clause is not a separate sentence but a subordinate clause, set apart by a comma and marked as subordinate by the connective adjunct" though". A great many subordinate clauses have their own subject, but they are not separate sentences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Energy production from coal in Germany followed a similar pattern, beginning the period at just under 60% and falling significantly **though**, unlike Denmark, it fell to a low of only 5% in 2007 and then increased again to approximately 18%.

***Although*** is a subordinating conjunction like ***but*** and in this case, the subject of the main clause is energy production and the subject of the subordinate clause is IT, which actually means energy production. Nothing wrong with that.

Here is a simple example:
Johnny loved reading though he loved cycling more.

The pronoun *he* is substituted for the subject Johnny, just like it for ***energy production***.